# How to implement custom watch task in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I am unsatisfied with `~ ;task1; task2;` so I want to implement my very own task that watches for changes and executes tasks. I.e. I need an sbt task that watches for some files and runs some tasks depending on what is changed.

e.g.

```
val task1: Initialize[Task[Int]] = ....
val task2: Initialize[Task[Int]] = ....

myTask := {
    log.info("Press Enter to stop watching...")
    while(isEnterNotPressedYet) {
        if (someFilesChanged)
            execute(task1) //start task1 and wait for its termination
        else if (someOtherFilesChanged)
            execute(task2)
        Thread.sleep(watchDuration.value)
    }
}
```

`task1.value` will not work because it will execute task1 BEFORE the body and only once. `dynTask` will not work because I want to execute tasks multiple times and without leaving the loop. Precisely, question is how to implement following:

```
def execute[T](task: Initialize[Task[T]]): T
def isEnterNotPressedYet: Boolean
```

Background:

I have web application that uses JS, Scala, sbt-revolver. Some resources support hot reloading (but still require compilation!), some does not. I.e. if *.js files change, I want to invoke `compileJs` task. If .scala files change, I want to invoke `re-start` task. But sbt watch has only one set of watched resources per project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to dive into SBT sources and implement it on my own.
There are quite a bit workarounds around strange SBT behavior but it works!

https://github.com/scf37/sbt-overwatch